# Getting a stack trace from io::Result()?

Tags: rust

In rust, if there is a deep tree of functions all calling IO operations that return the type io::Result, and use the question mark operator for error handling, how can you get a stack trace to see which IO operation failed?

E.g:

```
fn func2(param: u32) -> io::Result<u32> {
    perform_io1(param)?;
    perform_io2(param + 10)   
}

fn func1(param: String) -> io::Result<u32> {
    let v = perform_io3(param)?;
    perform_io4(v)?;
    let v2 = func2(v * 3)?;
    perform_io5()
}

fn main() {
    func1("test".to_string()).
        expect("func1 failed");
}
```

When run, if one of the IO operations in func1() or func2() fails, there will be an error like:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'func1 failed: Os { code: 16, kind: Other, message: "Device or resource busy" }', src/libcore/result.rs:1084:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

If executed with 'RUST_BACKTRACE=1', the backtrace isn't much more helpful:

```
   <snip>
   8: rust_begin_unwind
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:311
   9: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at src/libcore/panicking.rs:85
  10: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at src/libcore/result.rs:1084
  11: core::result::Result<T,E>::expect
             at /rustc/625451e376bb2e5283fc4741caa0a3e8a2ca4d54/src/libcore/result.rs:879
  12: example::main
             at src/main.rs:14
  13: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/625451e376bb2e5283fc4741caa0a3e8a2ca4d54/src/libstd/rt.rs:64
  14: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at src/libstd/rt.rs:49
  <snip>
```

The problem with this is it doesn't tell you which of the io operations caused the failure. "Device or resource busy" could potentially be caused by any of the IO operations.

What would be great is to get something like:

```
    thread 'main' panicked at 'func1 failed: Os { code: 16, kind: Other, message: "Device or resource busy" }', 
    - src/libcore/result.rs:1084:5
    - src/main.rs:3 - perform_io2(param + 10)
    - src/main.rs:9 - func2(v * 3)
    - src/main.rs:14 - func1("test".to_string())
```

Of course, this would mean that the ? operator would need to encapsulate the failure into each io:Err that was passed down until it got passed to expect().

What's the cleanest way to achieve this in Rust? Ideally one wouldn't have to add match expressions to the result of every io operation in order to log the result and pass it back. Or simply use unwrap() instead of ? (which would prevent handling the error more gracefully in main()).

Answer (score 1):

Of course after searching for some time and eventually asking a question, I find the solution 30 minutes later:

Enter the [error_chain](https://crates.io/crates/error-chain) crate:

So the resulting code would have to look something like:

```
#![recursion_limit = "1024"]

#[macro_use]
extern crate error_chain;

mod errors {
    error_chain!{}
}

use errors::*;

fn func2(param: u32) -> Result<u32> {
    perform_io1(param).chain_err(|| "failed to perform io1")?;
    perform_io2(param + 10).chain_err(|| "failed  to perform io2")
}

fn func1(param: String) -> Result<u32> {
    let v = perform_io3(param).chain_err(|| "failed to perform io3")?;
    perform_io4(v).chain_err(|| "failed to perform io4")?;
    let v2 = func2(v * 3).chain_err(|| "func2 failed")?;
    perform_io5().chain_err(|| "failed to perform io5")
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(ref e) = run() {
        use std::io::Write;
        let stderr = &mut ::std::io::stderr();
        let errmsg = "Error writing to stderr";

        writeln!(stderr, "error: {}", e).expect(errmsg);

        for e in e.iter().skip(1) {
            writeln!(stderr, "caused by: {}", e).expect(errmsg);
        }

        if let Some(backtrace) = e.backtrace() {
            writeln!(stderr, "backtrace: {:?}", backtrace).expect(errmsg);
        }

        ::std::process::exit(1);
    }
}

fn run() -> Result<()> {
    use std::fs::File;

    // This operation will fail
    func1("test".to_string()).
        .chain_err(|| "func1 failed")?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Based on: [the template recommended by Brian Anderson](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/error-chain/blob/master/examples/quickstart.rs)

Of course the error messages should be made to look nicer in a real world example.